# Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist

Tags: phpmyadmin

Всем привет, кто-нибудь может объяснить что это за ошибка и как ее исправить

[image]

Comment: Да выкиньте вы уже этот денвер к чертям собачьим, учитесь работать головой и руками.

Comment: тяжеловато, я ведь ещё ничего не знаю, кроме html css

Comment: P.S. А то докатитесь до [такого](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/6641/windows-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-path-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-mysql)

Comment: @Роман Соколов, а попробуйте :) Установка Apache, MySQL и PHP на свою машину с Windows - не такая уж непосильная задача. Зато когда пройдёте этот квест, скилы прокачаются очень хорошо. И многие вопросы, которыми вы сейчас готовы засыпать весь мир, отпадут как просто детские. Чесслово, самому легче будет двигаться дальше.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной задачи нам потребуется словарь, **Русский-Английский** или же, элементарный знания английского. И так мы имеем такую ошибку:

> 1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist

И так, мне словарь не понадобиться, ибо как я английский знаю, но вы им можете воспользоваться, там сказано:

> 1146 - Таблица 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' не существует.

Теперь вы проверяете эту таблицу, увидите, что ее нету, вставите ее туда и ошибка пропадет.

Comment: Суровый ответ.

Comment: Хе-хе, то известный глюк, всплывающий при удачном сочетании денвера и юзера :) Простым созданием таблицы от него не отделаться. Другой вопрос - нафига оно нужно...

Comment: @oOKomarOo, но правильный. Здесь форум программистов или где?

Comment: @klopp, полностью согласен :)

Comment: а если я базу данных удалю, ничего страшного не случится?

Comment: @Роман Соколов, нет, мировой ядерной войны не будет, и родственники не заболеют.

Comment: @klopp, как сказал, товарищ @oOKomarOo, суровый ответ :D

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в просторах интернета:

> Всё дело в файле  "config.inc.php" ,
> который приведен в статье Установка
> "phpMyAdmin 3.5.0"
> (http://php-myadmin.ru/learning/instrument-pma.html )
> Просто во второй части файла, которая
> дописывается после импорта таблиц,
> подчеркивание после 'pma' должно быть
> не одиночное, как указано в статье, а
> двойное. Потому что имена в базе - с
> двойным подчеркиванием!

Короче это косяк автора который писал мануал, полный код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
<?php
  $i = 0;
  $i++;
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'пароль'; /* Пароль пользователя root. */
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = 'localhost';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma'; /* Имя созданного вами только что пользователя для доступа к расширенным таблицам. */
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'пароль'; /* А здесь его пароль. */
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Эта ошибка показывает отсутствие базы для `phpmyadmin` (в ней он хранит настройки). Просто импортируйте в базу эти таблицы из `phpmyadmin/sql/**create_tables.sql**` так:

```
$ mysql -uroot -p < create_tables.sql
```

или через веб `phpmyadmin` в секции `import`